# В Visual Studio все заполнено пробелами

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

В Visual Studio все как будто заполнено пробелами, курсор можно поставить куда угодно, как это отключить?[image]

Comment: Включите отображение пробелов через Ctrl + R, Ctrl + W (по умолчанию) или Edit > Advanced > View White Space.

Comment: @alexsteeel не помогло, у меня стали отображаться настоящие пробелы и табы, но все еще можно выделить пустое место

Comment: TextEditor > All Languages > General > Убрать галку Enable virtual space

Comment: @alexsteeel сработало, спасибо.